# Trouble with loading a start page in tkinter

Tags: python, object, tkinter

So i am following a tutorial made på sentdex about tkinter, but i cant get the code to work somehow. I have tried to look through it many times, to make sure i did it the same way as he did, but the label wont show up. The code is supposed to show a startpage, but it just shows up blank. Anybody know what i have mistyped, or how to fix it?

```
#Import tkinter
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana",12)


#Creating class, where inhereting tk.TK
class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):
    #init intializes class. Runs method when class is intialized.
    def __init___(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)

        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        #sticky aligns with north south east or west
        frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)



app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `__init___` (three trailing underscores). `__init__()` is the correct spelling :)

You can further simplify things a bit by using `super()` and by building the `frames` dict with a literal:

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {
            StartPage: StartPage(container, self),
        }

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)


app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Omg thank you, i cant believe it was such a silly mistake, and thank you for the suggestion!